# remember me result is ignored by spring security, and i am still redirected to the login page

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

My Spring Security XML is as following:

```
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" requires-channel="https"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/" access="isAnonymous()" requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout-success" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout-success/" access="isAnonymous()" />     
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login/" default-target-url="/example/Login_execute"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logout-success" />
        <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>

        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
        </port-mappings>        
    </http>

...

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.myownpackage.UserAccountServiceImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="persistentTokenRepository" />
        <beans:property name="key" value="myownkey" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="persistentTokenRepository" class="com.myownpackage.PersistentTokenRepositoryImpl" />
```

Whenever I login and I tick the remember me, my program will save something to remember me database table (that's correct).

If I close my browser, re-open the browser, and open a page which requires authentication, my program will execute processAutoLoginCookie at PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices and returning correct UserDetails (that's also correct)

BUT, even so, I am still redirected to the login page.

By the way, the login page is customized, and what I do is just displaying JSP file with a form for login.

Is there any step I missed when writing the spring security XML?

Comment: Check the debug log output. When you are redirected, it should tell you why. Perhaps the user doesn't have role `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` for example, hence cannot access any other URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security's "Remember Me" uses a Cookie in the client side, which is your browser.

From [Spring's DOCS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me):

> Remember-me or persistent-login authentication refers to web sites
>   being able to remember the identity of a principal between sessions.
>   This is typically accomplished by sending a cookie to the browser,
>   with the cookie being detected during future sessions and causing
>   automated login to take place. Spring Security provides the necessary
>   hooks for these operations to take place, and has two concrete
>   remember-me implementations. One uses hashing to preserve the security
>   of cookie-based tokens and the other uses a database or other
>   persistent storage mechanism to store the generated tokens.

Spring's idea is that you will be able to login automatically between different Sessions:

**Server's** Sessions, meaning when the Server "bounces" (goes down and then up), are handled, for example, by Persistency.

**Clients'** Session are handled by the browser (Cookies). The browser uses a Cookie that Spring sends, the Server verifies this Cookie and lets the user login automatically , without the need to enter credentials again.

Check the Cookies within your browser.

HTH.

Ohad.